# How to create modular and extendable code for arbitrary feature extraction for machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

I have been working to create a Python module that performs feature extraction for feature to eventually be used by a machine learning algorithm down the line.

My approach has been to augment the initial gold standard dataset with (handcrafted) features, and thereby create a new dataset so training doesn't involve any feature creation, which can be expensive.  I believe this is the norm of most datasets--core features are always included (e.g. part-of-speech tags, named entity tags, semantic labels, etc.).

The dataset I am using only includes all of the sentences tokenized, formatted as XML tags.  For example:

```
<s>
  <lex begin='351' end='354'>The</lex>
  <lex begin='355' end='361'>people</lex>
  <lex begin='362' end='366'>here</lex>
  <lex begin='367' end='370'>are</lex>
  <lex begin='371' end='374'>far</lex>
  <lex begin='375' end='384'>wealthier</lex>
  <lex begin='384' end='385'>.</lex>
</s>
```

I would like to add additional information to each token, e.g. part-of-speech, NER, semantic labels, etc.

I have been using [Stanford NLP POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) and [Stanford NLP NER tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).  These are incredibly slow, but (hopefully) the speed provides more accurate POS and NER labels.  I also throw in another parser to get semantic labels.  Below is the new sentence, augmented with features.

```
<s>
    <lex ner='O' begin='351' end='354' pos='DT' label='None'>The</lex>
    <lex CATEGORY='#ref-category PERSON' begin='355' end='361'
        FORM='#ref-category COMMON-NOUN/PLURAL' ENDS-AT='#edges ending at 3'
        CONSTITUENTS='NIL' USED-IN='NIL' Type='SPARSER::EDGE' LEFT-DAUGHTER='#word "people"'
        pos='NNS' RULE='#PSR577  person -  "people"' label='SPATIAL_ENTITY'
        REFERENT='#people 1' POSITION-IN-RESOURCE-ARRAY='1' SPANNED-WORDS='NIL'
        RIGHT-DAUGHTER=':SINGLE-TERM' ner='O' Class='#STRUCTURE-CLASS SPARSER::EDGE'
        STARTS-AT='#edges starting at 2'>people</lex>
    <lex CATEGORY='#ref-category DEICTIC-LOCATION' begin='362' end='366'
        FORM='#ref-category PROPER-NOUN' ENDS-AT='#edges ending at 4'
        CONSTITUENTS='NIL' USED-IN='NIL' Type='SPARSER::EDGE' LEFT-DAUGHTER='#word "here"'
        pos='RB' RULE='#PSR271  deictic-location -  "here"' label='PLACE'
        REFERENT='#deictic-location "here" 3' POSITION-IN-RESOURCE-ARRAY='3'
        SPANNED-WORDS='NIL' RIGHT-DAUGHTER=':SINGLE-TERM' ner='O'
        Class='#STRUCTURE-CLASS SPARSER::EDGE' STARTS-AT='#edges starting at 3'>here</lex>
    <lex CATEGORY='#ref-category BE' begin='367' end='370'
        FORM='#ref-category VERB' ENDS-AT='#edges ending at 5' CONSTITUENTS='NIL'
        USED-IN='NIL' Type='SPARSER::EDGE' LEFT-DAUGHTER='#word "are"' pos='VBP'
        RULE='#PSR145  be -  "are"' label='None' REFERENT='#be 1'
        POSITION-IN-RESOURCE-ARRAY='4' SPANNED-WORDS='NIL' RIGHT-DAUGHTER=':SINGLE-TERM'
        ner='O' Class='#STRUCTURE-CLASS SPARSER::EDGE' STARTS-AT='#edges starting at 4'>are</lex>
    <lex CATEGORY='#word "far"' begin='371' end='374'
        FORM='#ref-category SPATIAL-PREPOSITION' ENDS-AT='#edges ending at 6'
        CONSTITUENTS='NIL' USED-IN='NIL' Type='SPARSER::EDGE' LEFT-DAUGHTER='#word "far"'
        pos='RB' RULE='(5)' label='None' REFERENT='#word "far"'
        POSITION-IN-RESOURCE-ARRAY='5' SPANNED-WORDS='NIL' RIGHT-DAUGHTER=':LITERAL-IN-A-RULE'
        ner='O' Class='#STRUCTURE-CLASS SPARSER::EDGE' STARTS-AT='#edges starting at 5'>far</lex>
    <lex ner='O' begin='375' end='384' pos='JJR' label='None'>wealthier</lex>
    <lex begin='384' end='385'>.</lex>
</s>
```

Obviously it's not really human readable anymore, but that's not important as these are just features to be piped to a machine learning algorithm.

For my purposes, I should only have to do this once, and less expensive features can just be added in right before training, e.g. is the word capitalized.

My present solution, however, is really terrible and I am not sure how to re-factor it, so that someone in the future can put in their own hooks/functions (e.g. they want to quickly add new features from some other parser) easily.  Here is my working solution:

```
xml_tokens_pattern = re.compile(r'<TOKENS>.+</TOKENS>', re.DOTALL)
sentence_pattern = re.compile(r'<s>.+?</s>', re.DOTALL)
lex_attrs_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=<lex)[^>]+')

class Feature_Process(object):
    """Wrapper for adding features to xmls.

    """
    def __init__(self, xmls, golddir, newdir='', suffix='++',
                 feature_functions=[], renew=False, debug=False):
        self.xmls = xmls
        self.golddir = golddir
        self.newdir = newdir
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.feature_functions = feature_functions
        self.renew = renew
        self.debug = debug
        self.heavy = False

    def process(self):
        for xml in self.xmls:
            path = setup_newdir(xml, self.golddir, self.newdir,
                                self.suffix, self.renew)
            if not path:
                continue
            mkparentdirs(path)
            with open(xml, 'r') as oldfile:
                text = oldfile.read()
            doc = Space_Document(xml)
            tags = [tag for tag in doc.tags if 'start' in tag.attrib]
            new_text = text
            for (i,m) in enumerate(re.finditer(sentence_pattern, text)):
                sentence = doc.sentences[i]
                doc_lexes = sentence.getchildren()
                xml_sentence = m.group()
                tokens = [''.join([c if ord(c) < 128
                                   else u2ascii[c]
                                   for c in x.text]).encode('utf-8')
                          for x in doc_lexes]
                (pos_tags, ner_tags, edges) = ([], [], [])
                if self.heavy:
                    pos_tags = pos.tag(tokens)
                    ner_tags = ner.tag(tokens)
                    try:
                        if self.debug:
                            print ' '.join([x for x in tokens])
                        edges = p(' '.join([x for x in tokens]), split=True)
                    except:
                        'somehow got here'
                c = 0
                for (j, n) in enumerate(re.finditer(lex_attrs_pattern,
                                                    xml_sentence)):
                    doc_lex = doc_lexes[j]
                    new_lex = Lex(doc_lex.text, doc_lex.attrib)
                    attributes = n.group()
                    tag = binary_search((int(doc_lex.attrib['begin']),
                                         int(doc_lex.attrib['end']),
                                         doc_lex.text), tags)
                    label = 'None'
                    if type(tag) != type(None):
                        label = tag.tag
                    new_lex.add(('label', label))
                    new_lex.add(('word', new_lex.text.encode('utf-8')))
                    if type(tag) != type(None):
                            new_lex.addAll([(key, tag.attrib[key]) for key in tag.attrib])
                    if pos_tags:
                        if tokens[j] == pos_tags[c][0]:
                            new_lex.add(('pos', pos_tags[c][1]))
                            pos_tags.remove(pos_tags[c])
                    if ner_tags: #this error case comes up for RFC/Durango.xml
                        if tokens[j] == ner_tags[c][0]:
                            new_lex.add(('ner', ner_tags[c][1]))
                            ner_tags.remove(ner_tags[c])
                    if edges:
                        sparser_edge = ledge(edges, tokens[j])
                        if sparser_edge:
                            if sparser_edge.keyvalues:
                                keyvalues = sparser_edge.keyvalues[sparser_edge.keyvalues.keys()[0]]
                                new_lex.addAll([(key, keyvalues[key]) for key in keyvalues])
                    new_lex.addAll([function(new_lex) for function in self.feature_functions])
                    new_text = new_text.replace(attributes, str(new_lex))
            w = open(path, 'w')
            print>>w, new_text
            w.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're going to use XML as your source and target, it's almost always a mistake to try to parse the XML by hand. Use the Python XML parsing libraries, of which there are several, to generate a structure or a stream you can manipulate.

If your primary goal is providing an API to add lexical features that can be interpreted by a classifier, my only recommendation is to clearly separate the serialization/deserialization from the manipulation of the data structures. But with such a simple case, that's not particularly hard.